# Hiveserver2: could not start ThriftHttpCliService

Tags: http, ssl, hive, port

I'm attempting to enable SSL on hiveserver2.

I can run in the default binary mode fine. http mode works no problem. As soon as I enable SSL through hive-site.xml, i'm faced with the following error.

> ERROR [Thread-28] thrift.ThriftCLIService: Error starting HiveServer2: could not start ThriftHttpCLIService
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use

There is nothing using any of the ports, prior to starting hiveserver2. Checked with `netstat -tupln`

Ports i've configured in hive-site.xml are

`hive.server2.webui.port 11002
 hive.server2.thrift.http.port 11001
 hive.server2.thrift.port 11000`

and invoking hiveserver2 via the service `/opt/hive/bin/hive --service hiveserver2 &`

O/S ubuntu (on kubernetes)
Hive version 3.0.0

Any help greatly appreciate. Google search for problems with ThriftHTTPCliService came up short.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that come across this post.

I upgraded to Hive 3.1.0, along with the metastore schema.

This fixed the issue, although unsure as to the underlying cause.